# Line integral between curve generated by intersection of a plane and surface

Tags: calculus, analysis, line-integrals

$$\int_D (xy)\mathrm{d}x-x^2\mathrm{d}y+z\mathrm{d}z$$  where $D:\ x^2+y^2-4z^2=1 ; z=1$

I can't seem to figure out how to make the figure nor what are the parametrics, I thought they would be: $x(t)=\sqrt5\cos t ; y(t)=\sqrt5\sin t ; z(t)=1$ where $t \in[0,2\pi]$ I think.

I should be able to solve this problem after I learn how to figure these 2 things out, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Did my answer solve your query? If not, feel free to comment on where I was not clear :)

Comment: Hello and thanks, I am a bit confused when we plug in z=1 isn't it $x^2+y^2=5$? And also I assume the domain I chose is right since I don't have a condition like y=>0 where it would be $t \in[0,\pi]$ instead of the one I mentioned above right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have edited the answer now. Yes, the domain and parameterization looks right to me, but I didn't get what you meant "condition like $y \implies 0$"

Comment: I meant to say y to be equal or higher than $0$, I don't know how to type it in with the format since it's the first day I am posting, bear with me until I get used to it haha. Also so the parameterization is correct without the $sqrt(5)$ ? 
Since I edited my post a few minutes ago when I was thinking about it.

Comment: The parameterization should be with the $\sqrt{5}$ for easiest evaluation, however had it been $x^2 +y^2=1$ (the mistaken result I had written), then without $\sqrt{5}$ would be good.

Comment: But, yes , I think I get what you mean since it's over the whole loop and the cosine and sine give nice parameterization, no need to worry about that. Run the $t$ from $[0 , 2 \pi}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this definetly helped me and I would've loved to upvote but I can't since the reputation :(

Comment: It is no problem, I forgot to say welcome to MSE :) My only suggestion for future question would be to make more 'general' titles so others may find use from your question as well

Comment: I see, I will keep it in mind!

Comment: Also, if I don't waste your time already too much, I did the figure as well could you check it if it seems alright? I don't know the format to post an image so I'll just put the link: https://imgur.com/V7qNTps

Comment: You can put the image into the question by pressing copy and pasting the image into the text box(if you are on computer). As per the question, the projection is unneccesary, you can directly think of it as integrating over the loop $r(t) = <cos t , sin t , 1>$

Comment: I see thanks, have a good day!

Comment: I have observed with your last few questions that you seem to have made efforts but you do not put it in the body of the question. You seem to use comments for providing details later when asked. That is not a good practice. The site expects you to show your effort in order to help so please always put as much information as you can in the body of the question. Otherwise you run the risk of question getting downvoted and / or closed. On the other hand adding your effort may get you upvotes and get you reputation on the site.

Comment: Yes, I am not used to it yet, I will keep it in mind for future. And yeah, I had a question where I put the answer in one of the comments and the whole comments "thread" got deleted over night, I am not aware why or how but yea, will do it from now on! Also after I accept the answer that someone provides, do I also put it in the body of the question or is it enough to leave it there and other people will see that I have accepted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am guessing you mean that you are cofined to move in the circular cross section of the surface and plane $z=1$. We can get the cross section by plugging $z=1$ into the surface's equation:

$$ x^2 + y^2 = 5$$

Returning to line integral:

$$ \int_D (xy)dx - x^2 dy + z dz$$

Note that since we don't move in the z direction, the last integral is zero. This leads to:

$$ \int_D (xy)dx - x^2 dy $$

After this you can parameterize as with $ x =\sqrt{5} \cos(t) $ and $y=  \sqrt{5}\sin(t)$

Comment: Thank you @MathLover 

Comment: @tryingtosolvethisspain you seem to have enough reputation now to upvote :) in any case as you are new, I want to let you know that if you find an answer helps you, you can accept the answer. It does encourage others to respond to your questions. If there are multiple answers, choose the one that you find the best as you can accept only one answer. This may guide you - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287

Comment: I see, I didn't notice it until you linked the guide about the accept answer button, I did it now!